# PDDoc.Save Adobe Acrobat method not working in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

Our office runs Arobat DC Pro and Excel 2016, we have been using the code below (scaled down version) in Excel VBA for years to save ***active*** Adobe PDF documents (that is, the open PDF doc that most recently had focus).

Since recently upgrading Arobat DC Pro to a newer version, the Acrobat **PDDoc.Save** method no longer works. It does not throw an error, it just doesn't save the active PDF.

I have had our IT dept. do an uninstall/reinstall of Acrobat PRO on a couple of computers but code still does not work.

Note, the Adobe Acrobat reference library is selected in VBA.

Any suggestions on how to fix?

```
Sub SaveActivePDF()

Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
Dim PdDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim avdoc As Acrobat.CAcroAVDoc

Dim boolWasSaved As Boolean

Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set avdoc = AcroApp.GetActiveDoc
Set PdDoc = avdoc.GetPDDoc

DayTime = Format(Now, "yymmddhmmss")
Username = Environ("USERNAME")

PdfNewPath = "C:\Users\" & Username & "\Desktop\TEST PDF " & DayTime & ".pdf"

boolWasSaved = PDDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, PdfNewPath)   '<-- NOT WORKING 

If boolWasSaved = True Then
        MsgBox "PDF WAS SAVED!"
    Else: MsgBox "ERROR - PDF not saved"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

For the record, access to the Acrobat library was blocked by sofware updates that changed default settings.

The issue was resolved as follows: Open any PDF > Edit > Preferences > Security (Enhanced) > ** UNCHECK ** check box "Enable Protected Mode at startup (Preview)" > exit all PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

VBA idle->press "F2"-> search "AcroPDDoc"->locate its method "Save"

```
Function Save(nType As Integer, sFullPath As String) As Boolean
```

In Adobe's *acrobatsdk_iacguide.pdf*, description of Parameter nType is a little bit confusing. Not sure what integer is for *PDSaveFull*

> **nType** is a logical OR of one or more of the following flags: PDSaveIncremental — Write changes only, not the complete file. This
> will always result in a larger file, even if objects have been
> deleted.
>
> *PDSaveFull* — Write the entire file to the filename specified by
> szFullPath.
>
> *PDSaveCopy* — Write a copy of the file into the file specified by
> szFullPath, but keep using the old file. This flag can only be
> specified if PDSaveFull is also used.
>
> *PDSaveCollectGarbage* — Remove unreferenced objects; this often reduces
> the file size, and its usage is encouraged. This flag can only be
> specified if PDSaveFull is also used.
>
> *PDSaveLinearized* — Save the file optimized for the web, providing hint
> tables. This allows the PDF file to be byte-served. This flag can only
> be specified if PDSaveFull is also used.